# Bypass warning using "If Field Value Is" using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, boolean

I'm using the "If Field Value Is" in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder so that the naming of the output file is different based on each selection earlier.
I get the warning "The process did not execute because the precondition is false.", which is indeed what I want to happen but I was wondering if it is possible to bypass the error message?
Or is there a way to run the naming for the different scenarios and then for example run a last tool with both as input (e.g., as precondition)?[image]